# Set status code in Grape gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape, grape-api

How does one customise the status code response when using the Grape gem?  e.g.

```
post do
   status = :accepted
   @order = Order.find(params[:id])
end
```

This can be achieved for with  error!({ error: 'Order not found'}, 404) but how does one do it for non errors?

Comment: http://rdoc.info/github/intridea/grape/Grape/Endpoint#status-instance_method

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
post do
  status 203
  @order = Order.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code I see that you are using `@order` but you did not define it previously so it did not found in view and giving error

Hope your code look like as you update a status so you can use `put` instead of `post`

```
 put ':id' do
   @order = Order.find(params[:id])
   @order.update_attributes!(:status, :accepted)
 end
```

or for `post`

```
 post do
   @order = Order.new
   @order.status = :accepted
   @order.save!
 end
```

Comment: Thanks I'll update my question to reflect your change.